# Allocation Unit ID calculation is incorrect?

Tags: sql-server, database-internals

I am reading the article http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-how-are-allocation-unit-ids-calculated/ on how to calculate the allocation unit ID based on m_indexId and m_objID. Then I try that on one of my database, by executing the command below:

```
    DBCC TRACEON(3604);
    DBCC PAGE (UFDATA_008_2013, 1, 73057, 3);
    GO
```

And the output result is:

```
    PAGE HEADER:


    Page @0x10008000

    m_pageId = (1:73057)                 m_headerVersion = 1                  m_type = 1
    m_typeFlagBits = 0x0                 m_level = 0                          m_flagBits = 0x8000
    m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = 1913890731                                  m_indexId (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 0
    Metadata: AllocUnitId = 406903719657472                                   Metadata: PartitionId = 406903719657472
    Metadata: IndexId = 1                Metadata: ObjectId = 1913890731      m_prevPage = (1:92774)
    m_nextPage = (0:0)                   pminlen = 11                         m_slotCnt = 61
    m_freeCnt = 3241                     m_freeData = 4829                    m_reservedCnt = 0
    m_lsn = (4028:6215:30)               m_xactReserved = 0                   m_xdesId = (0:0)
    m_ghostRecCnt = 0                    m_tornBits = 0
```

Then I use the formula in the above article to calculate the allocation Unit ID as (0 << 48) + (1913890731 << 16) = 125428742946816, which does not equal to the output Metadata: AllocUnitId(406903719657472). Why?

I can confirm the page is allocated, since I use the following command to list all the pages allocated to table ‘AADomDataColSet’:

```
       DBCC TRACEON(3604);
       Dbcc ind(UFDATA_008_2013, ‘AADomDataColSet’, -1);
```

And the result is below:

[image: Output result for AADomDataColSet]

You can find the page (1, 73057) is allocated to this object.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This seems identical to a case discussed in the comments to Paul's post. He indicated the cause is that the page is no longer allocated (notice metadata IndexId = 1, but m_indexid = 0).

Decoding the allocation unit ID using Paul's script:

```
DECLARE @alloc BIGINT = 406903719657472;
DECLARE @index BIGINT;
 
SELECT @index =
    CONVERT (BIGINT,
        CONVERT (FLOAT, @alloc)
            * (1 / POWER (2.0, 48)) -- right shift, reciprocal of left shift
    );
SELECT
    CONVERT (BIGINT,
        CONVERT (FLOAT, @alloc - (@index * CONVERT (BIGINT, POWER (2.0, 48))))
            * (1 / POWER (2.0, 16)) -- right shift, reciprocal of left shift
    ) AS [m_objId],
    @index AS [m_indexId];
```

Result:

[image: Result screenshot]

This matches the m_objid in your `DBCC PAGE` output.

#### Updated question

The calculation is correct if an index ID of 1 is used, again using the formula in Paul's post:

```
SELECT allocation_id =
    1 * CONVERT (BIGINT, POWER (2.0, 48)) | -- index id
    1913890731 * CONVERT (BIGINT, POWER (2.0, 16)); -- object id
```

[image: Allocation id result]

So your actual question seems not to be about the allocation unit calculation at all; rather you are asking why `DBCC PAGE` shows  `m_indexId (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 0` when the page is allocated and associated with index 1 - as shown in the `DBCC IND` output.

That, I don't know offhand. What I do know is that the calculation works both ways for me, testing on SQL Server 2012 build 6518. Perhaps there is something about your SQL Server version or table that means `AllocUnitId.idInd` is not being reported correctly. Without specific, reproducible details, you might have to ask Paul himself (though he's currently on holiday).

It's probably some edge case. For example, [this post](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/) says that there may be differences in `m_indexId` if the database was upgraded from SQL Server 2000. Try rebuilding the table, that oftens sorts these sorts of things out.